# reading certain characters with fgetc

Tags: c, fgetc

I am trying to create a spell checking program that takes an input file and makes sure each word is correct by searching through a dictionary file. The problem i am facing  is that when i try to take each word seperated by spaces from the input file and put it into a `char []` the words with `"` for some reason print

```
H0
i1
c0
h1
r2
i3
s4
!5
â0
1
2
h3
o4
w5
w6
â7
8
9
a0
r1
42
e3
y0
o1
u2
.3
```

the integers are my index

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "dict.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    FILE *fdict,*input;
    int i;
    char ch;

/* the biggest posible word is 30 plus a possible of two " or ' characters and the null character. so the limit of the array is 33*/ 
    char norm[33];

    if ( argc < 3 ) /* argc should be 3 for correct execution*/
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"1 or 2 Files were missing.");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ( argc > 3 ){
        fprintf(stderr,"too many Arguments");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* We assume argv[1] and agrv[2] are filenames to open*/
    fdict = fopen( argv[1], "r" );/* file pointer for the dictionary file*/
    input = fopen( argv[2], "r" );/*file pointer for the input file*/

    /* fopen returns NULL on failure */
    if ( fdict == NULL ){
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not open file: %s\n", argv[1] );/*checks to make sure the dictionary file can be opened*/
        exit(1);
    }

    if ( input == NULL ){
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not open file: %s\n", argv[2] );/*checks to make sure the input file can be opened*/
        exit(1);
    }
            /* Read one character at a time from file, stopping at EOF, which
                indicates the end of the file. Note that the idiom of "assign
                to a variable, check the value" used below works because
                the assignment statement evaluates to the value assigned. */
    while ( ( ch = fgetc( input ) ) != EOF ) {          

        char word[33] = "";/* resets the array*/

        for ( i = 0; !isspace( ch ) ; i++ ){
            word[i] = ch;
            printf("%c%d\n",ch,i);/* checking to see what is wrong with the index*/
            ch = fgetc( input );

        }


    }
    fclose( fdict );
    fclose( input );

    return 0;

}
```

my input looks like:

```
Hi chris! “howw” are you.
```

Comment: Note: `char ch;` should be `int ch;` to differentiate `EOF` from other `char`.

Comment: Are you using a word processor of some sort? Don't. Use a programmer's editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"` is not the same as `“` nor `”`.  (3 different quote marks.) Based on different encodings, these 3 characters use various sequences of `char` to represent them yet code only prints one `char` at a time.

Suggest just using the simpe quote mark `"`.

A simple or programmer's text editor would do.  Avoid a word processor that may bring in non-ASCII quote marks until your code is ready for that (@n.m.)